# c++ draw something with mouseclick on picturebox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have two functions for picurebox. I want to draw something with mouseclick on picturebox.

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_MouseClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        int Curx = e->X;
        int Cury = e->Y;
}
```

and

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {
            e->Graphics->DrawEllipse(Pens::Blue, 200,200, 1, 1);
}
```

I want to use one function in another.

Comment: This isn't C# code, try to avoid putting more than one programming language tag.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it looks like C++ with .NET extensions, making it something of an odd duck.

Comment: @MarkRansom it is, the .NET tag needs to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `private` section of the code where you have the picture box defined add two variables for the position, x and y as:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pictureBox1;
int mousex;
int mousey;
```

Set your `MouseClick` event to save the coordinates to those variables and force a repaint by calling `Refresh()`:

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_MouseClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
{
    mousex = e->X;
    mousey = e->Y;
    pictureBox1->Refresh();
}
```

In the `Paint` event, draw your ellipse at the coordinates you have saved in `mousex` and `mousey`:

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) 
{
   e->Graphics->DrawEllipse(Pens::Blue, mousex, mousey, 60, 60);
}
```

Adjust the width and height of the ellipse, currently 60 each to your choice.